# Can I store my own sql query by mysql special function and execute stored query later?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use mysql 5.6.11-win32.

I am not aware if there is way to tell mysql to store any query inside mysql's database(like information_schema or mysql) but not inside my own database.

I want to type query and then store it by some mysql special function. Later on future sessions I want to retrieve that query and execute it. Just like we do with stored procedures.

Is it possible to store query in mysql for later executions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If by "query" you mean "SELECT query", then you want to [create views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html). Views essentially create a pseudo-table that you can even include in larger queries.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT something FROM my_table WHERE some_twisted_condition;

SELECT * FROM my_view; -- returns the result of "SELECT something FROM my_table WHERE some_twisted_condition;"
SELECT * FROM my_view JOIN another_table USING something;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something along the lines of a [MySQL stored procedure or function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html):

> Stored routines (procedures and functions) are supported in MySQL 5.0. A stored routine is a set of SQL statements that can be stored in the server. Once this has been done, clients don't need to keep reissuing the individual statements but can refer to the stored routine instead.
>
> Stored routines require the proc table in the mysql database. This table is created during the MySQL 5.0 installation procedure. If you are upgrading to MySQL 5.0 from an earlier version, be sure to update your grant tables to make sure that the proc table exists. See Section 4.4.9, “mysql_upgrade — Check Tables for MySQL Upgrade”.

This is a common idiom used across many RDBMS to provide quoted functionality and seperating data logic from an application layer.

Another option is to use [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html) which are pseudo tables that are a the result of a query applied across one or more tables.

Comment: Thanks! I realise that stored procedure is just for storing and reusing queries.

Comment: To me this sounds like what you want: "storing" a query inside the database for later use. Have I misunderstood? Hope it helps regardless :)

Comment: Added mention of views as this is another good solution: thanks RandomSeed.